# Add a custom field to an order in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

In WooCommerce, I would like to add a new custom field to order details. I now that I can use use the code below to create a new custom field 'referenceNumber' and adds in it "ordercreated" value:

```
update_post_meta($order_id, 'referenceNumber', 'ordercreated']);
```

What I would like is to make that through checkout once an order is placed.

But it doesn't work it doesn't add a new custom field to order details page and don't add the value 'ordercreated', as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

So the question is how to add a custom field when an order is placed in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add a custom field to an order you can use:

- WordPress `update_post_meta()` function *(from an order id)*:

  ```
  $order_id = $order->get_id(); // If needed

  update_post_meta($order_id, 'referenceNumber', 'ordercreated'); // add and save the custom field
  ```
- WooCommerce `WC_Data` `update_meta_data()` method *(from the order object or the order id)*:

  ```
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // If needed: Get the WC_Order object from the order Id

  $order->update_meta_data('referenceNumber', 'ordercreated'); // Add the custom field

  $order->save(); // Save the data
  ```

Where `referenceNumber` is the **meta key** and `ordercreated` is the **meta value**. Both works.

---

Now to add a custom field to an order **when customer place an order**, you can use:

- `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` action hook *(before order data is saved - used to adjust order data before it's saved)*:

  ```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_custom_field_on_placed_order', 10, 2 );
  function add_custom_field_on_placed_order( $order, $data ){
      $order->update_meta_data( 'referenceNumber', 'ordercreated' );
  }
  ```
- `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`  action hook *(order already exist - used to add custom meta data)*:

  ```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_custom_field_on_placed_order', 10, 2 );
  function add_custom_field_on_placed_order( $order_id, $data ){
      update_post_meta($order_id, 'referenceNumber', 'ordercreated');
  }
  ```
- `woocommerce_checkout_order_created`  action hook *(order already exist - to trigger an action or also to add custom meta data)*:

  ```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'add_custom_field_on_placed_order', 10, 2 );
  function add_custom_field_on_placed_order( $order_id, $data ){
      $order->update_meta_data( 'referenceNumber', 'ordercreated' ); // Add the custom field
      $order->save(); // Save data (as order exist yet)
  }
  ```

  Or:

  ```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'add_custom_field_on_placed_order' );
  function add_custom_field_on_placed_order( $order ){
      update_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'referenceNumber', 'ordercreated');
  }
  ```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had a similar requirement few days ago, as i needed to add new field at checkout. Following article helped me. You can check it too. Here is the link. Basically you will have a write a function which will use woo commerce hook **"woocommerce_default_address_fields"**
https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/add-custom-fields-woocommerce-checkout-page/

Comment: Thank you so much but we its not related to checkout by any mean its related to save data of payment gateway to order details